# How to make tar use constant memory?

Tags: linux, command-line, memory, compression, tar

I need to compress multiple files across multiple folders (>32GB) the way we compressed before via code used too much memory, so I used `tar` instead. I used tar with lz4 with

`tar -I lz4 -cf foo.tar.lz4 -C [dir that contains all folders] [all folders to compress]`

And decompress with:

`tar -I lz4 -xf foo.tar.lz4 -C [target dir]`

We execute this tar command via a Python subprocess.

The results are rather disappointing, the compression time has not improved (even tho lz4 should be faster than zip, specifically at extraction), but the bigger problem is the memory consumption; as far as I can understand tar should use a constant memory but we found that it uses over 32 GB of memory.

Am I doing something wrong? How do I make tar stream the files instead of loading them all into memory?

We are using Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: Is it actually `tar` using the memory though? Or maybe the `lz4` process it starts? Or is it not used by programs at all but instead by the operating system for caches and buffers? It is not clear what you measured and how you did it. It is also not clear what the actual problem is. For example, LZ4 may be the faster algorithm, but can your storage keep up?

Comment: @DanielB thanks for the insightful answer. It could be that lz4 is using a lot of memory. However, as far as I can understand it receives a stream from tar rather than all the files, so it should really not be using more than constant memory. Am I wrong? I measure the memory via RSS memory. Does this type of memory metric count in caching?

Answer (score 0):

Tar may use constant memory, but Linux does not.

Your RAM usage may seem to increase because Linux is actively caching
the data read and written by the tar command, up to the limits of memory.

Unfortunately, it seems that `tar` itself can not be instructed to use
O_DIRECT or POSIX_FADVISE (both of which can be used to "bypass" the cache).

Comment: I don't see the point in caching - the data is streamed, and thus only accessed once. Is Linux "not smart enough" to maintain an LRU cache and evict the unused cache segments? Doesn't seem logical to me.

Comment: Another question - if this is indeed a result of caching, does that mean that if I allocate less RAM to the machine it will do with this smaller amount of RAM? (for example 4GB)

Comment: 4 GB is a bit small nowadays, but the answer is Yes in theory. No OS will evict cache memory unless that memory is needed - it doesn't relate to how you use that data.

Comment: I see. One last question. The metrics I am using to measure memory are for RSS memory. Is OS cache counted as RSS memory? If not, then it can't be it.

Comment: You should include in your post a screenshot of the memory usage.